# How can I access the features of an MQTT message in Java?

Tags: java, maven, mqtt, paho

I need to access messages' fields(header flags, message type etc.). I am using Paho to handle MQTT messages in my maven project. But I can only access topic, payload and quality of service. My callback function looks like this:

```
@Override
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(topic + "  " + message);
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this using Paho or do I have to use another tool or library?

Comment: Relevant if not duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65516789/how-to-read-header-keyvalue-pair-when-subscribing-a-message-with-paho-mqtt

Comment: Those are (topic, payload, qos, retained) the only fields in a MQTTv3 message, there is nothing else to read.